# How do I add a unique index on a field in a partitioned MySQL DB?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, unique

I have a table, foo, that is partitioned by 'created_at' and has its primary key as (`id`,`created_at`).  I.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `bar_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   ...

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(created_at))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (733712) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (733773) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (733832) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (733893) ENGINE = InnoDB,
...
)
```

How do I create a unique index such that `bar_id` is unique across all partitions? If I try something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_index USING BTREE ON foo (bar_id);
```

I receive the error:

```
ERROR 1503 (HY000): A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
```

But, if I include the partitioning function (`id`, `created_at`) when building the index then I end up with an index that does not guarantee that bar_id is unique.

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned that I already have a primary key on the table:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created_at`)
```

Also, bar_id can be NULL.

Comment: Hey, did you figure out a way? I am struggling with the exact same issue. I don't even understand why partition key has to be part of the unique keys. Can't make sense out of it.

Comment: @varunl, I have the same issue too. I need to use `start datatime` field as the partition key and i make it with the `id` filed as primary key, But i have to other fields  as UNIQUE KEY which are really need to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

The error message itself explains the problem. Please, read the manual,
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

"The rule is : All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have. In simple words, every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression."

Comment: It seems the pasted URL has been truncated.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I guess they moved it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

I have updated the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Primary Key.

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_5.1_partitions.html) on partitioning: any column used for a partitioning expression must be part of the table's primary key (if it has one) or (first) unique key (if it has a unique key but no primary key). Otherwise, you'll see the error message, "A PRIMARY KEY needs to include all fields in the partition function".

If a table has no primary key, but does have one or more unique keys, then any columns used in the partitioning expression must be part of the (first) unique key.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already have a primary key on the table: PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created_at`).  Also, bar_id can be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via a secondary table to store the unique `bar_id`, and a before-insert trigger.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Unfortunately, this means that I'd need to write a routine (or more) to handle cases where bar_id is updated to NULL or changed for a given row in foo, correct? Seems like a lot of overhead, which leads me to believe that there must be a simpler solution.